# Remove Stripe Woocommerce Credit Card Icons (and replace with image)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Trying to remove all of the Stripe credit card svg icons from the credit card option on the Woocommerce checkout page.

I see this:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/#section-39

But that just shows how to change one.

Any idea how to remove them all and place a 180 x 27 px .png image in their place?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to hide all icons is to add this to your child's functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'wc_stripe_payment_icons', 'hide_my_icons' );
```

Comment: Where is hide_my_icons defined? I don't see it in WordPress or WooCommerce.

Comment: @rup I can't remember what line it's on. I just always use this and then write my own icons.